# Heading and HR markdown conflict with each other

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, documentation

In the markdown [editing reference page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it states that horizontal rules could be made using the following:

> Insert a horizontal rule `<hr/>` by
>   putting three or more hyphens,
>   asterisks, or underscores on a line by
>   themselves:

```
Rule #1
---
Rule #2
*******
Rule #3
___
Rule #4    
- - - -
```

However, this is what this actually looks like:

### Rule #1

Rule #2

---

Rule #3

---

Rule #4

---

... you will notice that the first one is a heading instead of an `hr`. This is because the documentation also says that headings can be created using the following:

```
Header 1
========

Header 2
--------
```

> The number of = or - signs doesn't
>   matter; one will work. But using
>   enough to underline the text makes
>   your titles look better in plain text.

There is obviously a conflict here when someone tries inserting 3 or more `-` with no spacing in between them. It is ambiguous if it should be a heading or an `hr`. Currently it treats it as a heading.

Comment: Related: [Error in markdown help page (horizontal rules)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61038/335251)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Markdown spec itself](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) is ambiguous in several areas. So, this is by design.

Comment: Why not remove that item from the editing reference page. Let them use * * * or _ _ _ to < hr > things

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to avoid, just always have an empty line before horizontal lines.

**1.** Heading instead of horizontal line

### one

### two

three

```
one
---
two
---
three
```

**2.** Horizontal lines working as excepted

one

---

two

---

three

```
one

---
two

---
three
```