# Error in markdown help page (horizontal rules)

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, help-text

The [markdown help page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) currently states:

> ### Horizontal Rules
>
> Insert a horizontal rule <hr/> by putting three or more hyphens, asterisks, or underscores on a line by themselves:
>
> ```
> Rule #1
> ---
> Rule #2
> *******
> Rule #3
> ___
> ```

However, the first one (hyphens) is incorrect. It renders a header. Indeed the help page states that too, one section further up.

Hyphens with spaces in between render a rule though, so I recommend to change it so that it reads:

> Insert a horizontal rule <hr/> by putting three or more hyphens, asterisks, or underscores on a line by themselves. Hyphens must have a space between them:
>
> ```
> Rule #1
> - - -
> Rule #2
> *******
> Rule #3
> ___
> ```

Comment: Related: [Heading and HR markdown conflict with each other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54121/335251)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: I see, you mean the help page should have spaces too.

OK, I agree, checking that change in now.

Comment: I believe OP means the help page is wrong in that there aren't blank lines around the hyphens.